# Dual DVI w/ PR03X docked to E6320?

Tags: laptop, display, dvi, docking-station

Is there a cable (or splitter of some kind) I can use to drive two independent displays using the DVI port on the PR03X Dell docking station that's docked to a Dell E6320?

Comment: Swap for a PRO2X which includes dual DVI/dual DisplayPort (aka Dell E-Port Plus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [port on the docking station](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/416Qk7DLlWL.jpg) is a ['Dual-link' DVI-D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DVI_Connector_Types.svg), this does not mean it can run multiple displays. Your best solution would be to use a converter for the VGA slot to convert it to DVI.

First check that the docking station supports 2 displays from both of it's ports simultaneously, i can't find much documentation on it myself.

Comment: Just to be clear, all DVI ports have all the pins available but it doesn't mean they are dual link.  The ports on these Dell docking stations appear to be single link only - at least with a PR02X and a Latitude E7440 the two DVI ports only reported 1920x1200 as their maximum resolution, with a dual-link monitor and cable connected.

Answer (score 0):

DVI technology is not designed to be capable of running two displays. This is physically impossible. If you want additional displays I recommend yuo look into DisplayLink powered devices, they are effectively USB to DVI adaptors.

Comment: It *could* be used to run two displays, certainly wasn't designed for it but the DVI-I connection carries DVI (digital) aswell as VGA (analogue) so you could theoretically split the two signals. But no graphics cards would support this.